# BitBucket Pipeline - Build and deploy using node / gulp / git ftp

Tags: node.js, git, ftp, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I noticed yesterday that BitBucket supported CICD pipelines, which is an amazing feature I'm eager to use.

I have however some difficulty setting it up.

My building process in general:

- npm install
- npm install -g bower
- bower install
- npm install -g gulp
- gulp

The gulp command is building the HTML application and places the output to a `build` folder. After the build has been completed, I'd like the code to be transfered to a directory on my website.

This translates to the following `bitbucket.yml`:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm install -g bower
          - bower install --allow-root
          - npm install -g gulp
          - gulp
          - cd build
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://mywebsite.com/public_html/mydirectory
```

The issue I'm getting is that the `git ftp init` seems to be uploading the `src` folder, and not the contents of the `build` one which is created during the `gulp` step.

Any ideas?

---

**Update:** `--syncroot` does seem to be a partial fix. Meaning it does try to upload the `build` directory now. However, the problem at this point is that `git ftp` only seems to be syncing tracked files.

Because the files in the `build` folder are created during the pipeline build, that does not apply to those.

I have tried to add a file named `.git-ftp-include`, which as described should transfer untracked files. Sadly, I haven't been successful in deploying my code.

`.git-ftp-include` file contents:
    build/index.html:/src/index.html

Which basically says: upload `index.html` from the `build` syncroot whenever the `index.html` in the `src` directory is changed.

Answer (score 0):

For untracked files to be transferred by `git-ftp` the syntax in `.git-ftp-include` is [!filename](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md#syncing-untracked-files).

Comment: Actually the '!' implies that a file should always be uploaded. The notation I used, is used when you only want to upload files which are changed.

Plus, I have already tried the '!'  and didn't work out.

Comment: Have you found the way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I recommend that you use `ncftp`. In the Pipelines will be something like:

```
- apt-get -qq install ncftp
- ncftpput -v -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" -R $FTP_HOST /remote build/*
```